# Creating GET request in Java always returns SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, jsoup

Whenever I try to perform a GET request on a certain website (seen below) I always get a SocketTimeoutException. I only get this problem in Java, whereas if I try using Python's `requests` library I successfully manage to get the text.

```
String link = "https://www.yeezysupply.com/api/products/FV6125/availability";

        try {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(link);
            connection.header("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            Document document = connection.get();

            System.out.println(document.text());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is a screenshot of the error: https://prnt.sc/rp1ym9

Line 64 from my Main class is `Document document = connection.get();`

Also, when I use the Chrome extension 'PlugMan' I am able to successfully obtain the body from the site using a GET request, so clearly there is an issue with how I'm doing it in Java, because it works elsewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT, the site has a counter measure to prevent bots. The only way I got it to respond was using a user agent. This is how you'd set it with JSoup:

```java
Response resp = Jsoup.connect(link)
                  .userAgent("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15")
                  .followRedirects(true)                  
                  .execute();

Document document = resp.parse();
```

---

My original (and wrong) assumption kept for reference below:

I don't think this is a Java or coding issue. That site simply doesn't respond. Is the web site up, or possibly do you have a required proxy configured for Python and it's not used in the Java code? If that's the case, take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

When I try a simple wget from my workstation, the site doesn't answer:

```
$ wget https://www.yeezysupply.com/api/products/FV6125/availability

--2020-03-29 17:59:13--  https://www.yeezysupply.com/api/products/FV6125/availability
Resolving www.yeezysupply.com (www.yeezysupply.com)... 184.28.114.123, 184.28.114.129
Connecting to www.yeezysupply.com (www.yeezysupply.com)|184.28.114.123|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Operation timed out) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Comment: When visiting the site I do receive the message I'm looking for, the website is definitely up https://prnt.sc/rp20or

Comment: I upvoted this answer. Appears to me if the API were expecting a user agent or sort of, the intended consumer of the API could only be a UI page, possibly it’s own UI..

Comment: I imagine this service was originally built to service some Javascript-based UI, with the idea that if there's a UI, then there's a single user. Obvious, that's weak sauce, but that's definitely what's going on. If you just curl that URL, you get a fancy warning telling you you're a bot so you don't get to see :)

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks:

- `content-type` is not a request header. It's used to describe server response content.
  To indicate what you expect you should use `accept` header.
- It's a good habit to add `user-agent` header. Some servers don't respond without user agent and that's the case here.

```
connection.header("accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml");
connection.header("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0");
```

These two above make the connection possible but I have to disappoint you. Regardless of what you set in `accept` header the response contains JSON and Jsoup can't parse JSON, only HTML and XML. You'll have to use other library to download and parse it.

EDIT:
To download JSON to String using Jsoup, instead of

```
connection.get();
```

use:

```
connection.ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

Comment: How should I open the connection then? I can use GSON to parse the JSON response, but if Jsoup can't retrieve the data then how else can I do it?

Comment: Your updated answer got me exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!